# Same width for dropdown menu options when its content is variable

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

It seems to be a real silly problem, but I'm stuck at it and can't find a way out.

I'm working on a dropdown menu with pure CSS3 and all that I want is the following:

For now, I have this menu:

[image: Problem]

*Note the hovered option `cars` behavior.*

I want that the hovered element looks like the following:

[image: Possible solution]

[**Here is the jsFiddle for the example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/XjyMV/)

As I said, it could be a stupid question for some of you but I can't realize how to solve it right now.

I tryed `width: 100%` for a element inside the second `<ul>` but it doesn't work as I expected.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this solve the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/David_Knowles/rpF6E/

Added this:

```
.menu li li {
    float:none;
}

.menu li ul li a {   
    width: auto; /* instead of 100% */
    display:block;
}
```